# Add comma at end of each line

Tags: python, html, file, text

I have several html files in a folder, like this:

```
<html>
Hello Guys
Wassap Guys
Bye Guys
</html>
```

In Python I want to open the file and add comma , at end of each line Like this:

```
<html>,
Hello Guys,
Wassap Guys,
Bye Guys,
</html>,
```

Then bring them into one line like this:

```
<html>,Hello Guys,Wassap Guys,Bye Guys,</html>,
```

Here's what I tried:

```py
import os
for i in os.listdir():
    with open(i, "w+") as f:
        f.write(",".join(f.readlines())+",")
```

But when i run the module, it deletes all the contents of the html file and leaves only one comma

I also tried this code that a friend sent it to me

```
import glob
import os
files= glob.glob("C:\\test\\*.html")
for i in files:
    with open(i,'r') as in_file:
        out_file_name = os.path.basename(i)
        with open(f"C:\\test\\{out_file_name}",'w') as out_file:
            out_file.write(','.join(in_file.readlines())+',')
    in_file.close()
    out_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this. This gets the file, replaces the new line symbol `\n` with `,\n` to get what you want. Similar to Prune's answer but he adds it to the start of the line as well, my one only adds it to the end.

```py
import os
for i in os.listdir():
    with open(i, "r") as f:
        content = f.readlines()

    with open(i, "w") as f:
        lines = []
        for line in content:
            new_line = line.replace("\n","") + ",\n"
            lines.append(new_line)
        f.write("".join(lines))
```

Comment: i also added encoding="utf8", worked but i dont want to replace "\n" with ",\n". I want to bring them in one line. Find"[\n\r]+" Replace with "," works on Notepad++ but not working in python

Comment: I don't understand @Michael

Answer (score 2):

You opened the file in write-append mode.  Thus, `readlines` returns an empty list.
Instead, read the file, close it, and reopen in `w` mode to overwrite the original contents.

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    content = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]

with open("test.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(",\n".join(content)+",")
```

Comment: gives me err: expected an indented block

Comment: The posted code does not produce that error with Python 3.8.2; you'll have to post what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
file_name = "test_file"
string_to_add = "added"

with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
    file_lines = [''.join([x.strip(), string_to_add, '\n']) for x in f.readlines()]

with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(file_lines)
```